# Scrapy code throws TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Im trying to make a request for a parameter `site_search_url`, but I get the following error when I run: ``:

```
start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

code:

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    def __init__(self, site_search_url):
        self.site_search_url = site_search_url

    def start_requests(self):
        se_base = 'http://www.se.com/search?q=site:'
        start_urls = [ se_base + self.site_search_url, ]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: The error is simply that `start_requests` does not have an explicit return statement and so returns `None`. You are then attempting to iterate over the return value. To resolve it simply return something that is iterable from `start_requests`. I'm not privy to enough of your code to suggest what it might return.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `start_requests` returns nothing, which mean returns `None`  in Python, while it should return an iterable of `Request` objects. In your case easiest is to populate `start_urls` in `__init__` and don't override `start_requests`:

```
class BrickSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    se_base = 'http://www.se.com/search?q=site:'
    def __init__(self, site_search_url):
        self.start_urls = [self.se_base + site_search_url]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            response.urljoin(next_page),
            callback=self.parse
        )
```